# Travel restriction to USA from India for a PhD student (with F1 visa)

Tags: usa, student-visa, india, covid-19

I am currently a 4th year PhD student (with a valid F1 visa) who came to visit his family in India for a short trip but then due to the unfortunate circumstances, USA put a travel restriction on India. I read the rules carefully but the following concern is not clear to me.

Since I am a PhD student, technically I work every day for the whole year. So the rule says " if the program begins on or after 1st August, I will be eligible to travel 30 days before that..."

Now I am confused if I am allowed to travel on 1st July (which is a month before 1st August since techincally my program is continuing) or I have to wait till atleast 23 rd July (since the official fall semseter begins on 23rd August)? [I tried to contact consulate on this matter but didn't get any helpful reply.]

Also in this situation, while traveling, what should I carry as a proof for my starting date of program? Since my i20 is only showing that my program starts on 21st August 2017, so that may not be a best proof for this purpose.

Thank you in advance for any help...

Answer (score 1):

You currently cannot fly from India to the US.  You would have to spend at least 14 days in another country before entering the US.

Source: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php  -> USA:

> Students with an F-1 or M-1 visa and their F-2 and M-2 dependents. They must not arrive from or not have been in Brazil, China (People's Rep.), India or Iran in the past 14 days.

No idea whether these restrictions will be lifted by July 1, but I wouldn't count on it.

> Also in this situation, while traveling, what should I carry as a proof for my starting date of program? Since my i20 is only showing that my program starts on 21st August 2017, so that may not be a best proof for this purpose.

Look at the course end date specified in the I-20.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind answer. My i20 indicates that end date is Aug 2022. In this case, when can I enter in USA?